# Display angular-ui Modal with data from a REST request (with delay)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, promise, angular-ui-bootstrap, restangular

I want to open an [Modal Dialog (angular-ui)](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), but when the `open()` function is called, the data are not available. Data are loaded by a resource call so there's a delay.

I tried to play with the promise `opened`, but data are not changed.

```
  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        mydata: function() {
          return "Loading...";
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.opened.then(function() {
          $scope.mydata = $scope.loadData();
        }, function() {
          $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
      };


     $scope.loadData = function() {
        $timeout( function(){
          $log.info("data loaded");
          return "data loaded...";
        }, 3000)
      };
```

Something is missing in my understanding between the resolve property, the modal promises and the deferred loading.

(I would like to use restangular to load the resource).

Here is the sample :
http://plnkr.co/edit/Mj6JolD06DUJd6N6ECYi

Thanks in advance for any clue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mostly there.  The problem is in the way you coded the `loadData` function.  Since you are doing an asynchronous call you can't just do a return of data like that.  Instead, what you can do is in your `loadData` you can call a function on the modalInstance that will set a value in the $scope of the modal.

So in your ModalInstanceCtrl you can add a function like this:

```
$modalInstance.setMyData = function(theData) {
  $scope.mydata = theData;
};
```

And then you can call that in your loadData like this:

```
$scope.loadData = function(aModalInstance) {
  $log.info("starts loading");
  $timeout(function() {
    $log.info("data loaded");
    aModalInstance.setMyData("data loaded...");
  }, 3000);
};
```

You also need to make sure that you pass the instance of the modal when you call loadData:

```
modalInstance.opened.then(function() {
  $scope.loadData(modalInstance);
}, function() {
  $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

I created an updated plunk so you can see how it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/M7qfegYIOqOQekoxLaj5?p=preview

Comment: errr, why are you not returning the data and setting it in a global way instead? That's poor separation of concerns. Return the data from the promise and set it in a `.then` handler.

Comment: It's not being set in a global way, it's being set directly on the instance of the ModalInstanceCtrl. If I understand correctly, are you saying to return a promise in the resolve? You can do that but then it can cause UX issues when the modal is not opened until the data is available -- see here for that implementation: http://plnkr.co/edit/BIraJ9k9klTsl7MZ62jR?p=preview